# Pass Database Values to Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In my Zend application there is a layout file used in multiple modules. Now i need to retrieve data from database (table gateway) and display on layout. Then it should appear across all the modules.

How do i achieve that ?

[image]

Ex -

```
<?php echo $user_name; ?>
```

Value for $user_name should be taken from database and pass to layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to set it in every controller. You could just attach it to a layout variable in your module.php.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $tableWhatever = $sm->get('tableWhatever');
    $viewModel = $e->getApplication()->getMvcEvent()->getViewModel();
    $viewModel->userName = $tableWhatever->getUserName();
}
```

Depending on the zf2 version you may have to access the variable in your layout like so:

```
$this->layout()->userName;
```

You also have the possibility to extend the `AbstractActionController` and add the layout variables trough that. I usually just go with the quick onBootstrap method though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, in Zend, your controller(s) will want:

`$this->view->assign('variableName', 'variableValue');`

And in your view(s), you will want:

`$this->variableName;`

Comment: Do i have to add this in every module controller ?

Comment: Yes. It is common for each controller to have an associated layout, and for that controller to be responsible for gathering data that is passed to its layout. The above line in the controller is very lightweight, and is acceptable to put across many controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Zend Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) to achieve something like that, like:

```
class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
      // Get instance
      $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
      $view = $layout->getView();

      $view->user_name = 'your_username';
    }
}
```

and register your plugin in frontController:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->registerPlugin(new MyPlugin());
```

then in layout , you could do:

```
<?php echo $this->user_name; ?>
```

Comment: Is this for Zend 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @ChamingaD see updated answer its for Zend Framework 2